# what is the use of insert mode on AJAXFORM in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

When i am clicking the ajax from is loaded the partila view correctly inside the div have id as mytraget. But my question is what is the use of insertmode in ajax form.

On submitting the ajax form it always load the partial view inside of the div have id as mytraget on all type of insert mode. Then what is the of insert mode?

My original view named as MyView

```
@model Example.Models.mytest

<div id="mytraget"> </div>

@using(Ajax.BeginForm("myParialAjax", new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore, UpdateTargetId = "mytraget" }))
{
    <p>Name</p> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.string1)

    <input type="submit"  value="Submit" />
}
```

My Cobtroller Method

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult myParialAjax(mytest s)
{
    return PartialView("Mypartial", s);
}
```

My Parial view which is named as **Mypartial**

```
@model Example.Models.mytest

<p> 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m =>m.string1)
</p>
```

In all  type of insert mode i  get partial view inside of the the below div.
**Output :**

```
<div id="mytraget">
    <p>
        <input id="string1" type="text" value="asdf" name="string1">
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got myself the answer What i am missing is Need to insert some tags inside of the target tag.

Like below:

```
@model Example.Models.mytest

<div id="mytarget">
    <p> my para </p>
</div>

@using(Ajax.BeginForm("myParialAjax", new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore, UpdateTargetId = "mytarget" }))
{
    <p>Name</p> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.string1)

    <input type="submit"  value="Submit" />
}
```

Now here **InsertionMode.InsertBefore** will insert my partial view **above the paragraph tag** and **InsertionMode.InsertAfter** will insert my partial view **after the paragraph tag** and **InsertionMode.Replace** will **replace the whole things which is inside of the tag** with my target id.